# We draw real number from set non-negative and not exceeding $20$. What's the average length of randomed number from $0$?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

We draw real number from set non-negative and not exceeding $20$.

**a)** What's the avarage absolute value of randomed number from $0$?

**b)** What's the standard deviation from that value?

**c)** What's the name of distribution?

**Could anyone check if my solution is correct?**

**c)**
Uniform distribution

**a)**
$x\in [0,20)$

$E(X) = \frac{b+a}{2}= \frac{20+0}{2}=10$

So average length of randomed number from $0$ is $10$

**b)**
$\text{Var}(X)=\frac{(b-a)^{2}}{12}=\frac{400}{12}$

so Standard devation = $\sqrt{\frac{400}{12}}$

Comment: Considering the formulation, we can safely assume a uniform distribution, so everything is fine.

Comment: But "length" of a number and "not lesser" are not the suitable terminologies here. The "length" is in this case just the number itself (distance from the origin) and it should be "less than $20$" (or equivalent in this case : "less than or equal to $20$")

Comment: @Peter It is 'less then 20', I am translating it from my languange so I might make mistakes in terminology. Did I understood it correctly that E(x) is the average length from origin? (0)

Comment: Correct, the expected value (here $10$) is also the average of the occuring random numbers, if we repeat the draw very very often assuming the draws are actually independent. To be more rigorous : The average will tend to the expected value almost surely (with probability $1$) , if the number of trials tends to $\infty$.